# Remove the Padding from an HTML Select Menu

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How can I remove the top/left padding in a select menu?

[image]

I tried setting the padding and margin to 0 but that had no effect. Here is the HTML:

```
<form class="timePeriodMenu">
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <select name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2" multiple>
            <optgroup>
                <option value="1">last 30 days</option>
                <option value="6" selected="selected">past 6 months</option>
                <option value="12">past 12 months</option>
                <option value="300">list all</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wccnuxgt/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space you referring inside your image is not `padding` it's the space occupied by the `optgroup` tag inside your `Select` tag. And it cannot be removed due to browser-limitations of `SELECT` tag along with your `HTML` approach. The indentation on `left` is to represent grouping structure.

If you don't want that space, then don't use the `optgroup` tag and instead go directly for `option` as shown in below Fiddle.
**Check Demo 1**

Or if you still want to keep that `optgroup` tag, you can do a CSS hack, to remove the `vertical-space` but it won't help you in removing the `left` side space.
**Check Demo 2**

```css
.demo-2 optgroup {
  font-size: 0;
}

.demo-2 option {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
DEMO 1 - Removing OPTGROUP tag

<form class="timePeriodMenu demo-1">
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <select name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2" multiple>
      <option value="1">last 30 days</option>
      <option value="6" selected="selected">past 6 months</option>
      <option value="12">past 12 months</option>
      <option value="300">list all</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<hr> DEMO 2 - Keeping Optgroup, but removing vertical-space with CSS hack.

<form class="timePeriodMenu demo-2">
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <select name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2" multiple>
      <optgroup label="German Cars">
        <option value="1">last 30 days</option>
        <option value="6" selected="selected">past 6 months</option>
        <option value="12">past 12 months</option>
        <option value="300">list all</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

In **Chrome** and **Opera** the user agent style sheet is adding a ::before element to the select:

```
select:-internal-list-box optgroup option::before {
    content: "    ";
}
```

If you want a CSS fix this should do it:

```css
.demo-2 optgroup {
  font-size: 0;
}

.demo-2 option {
  font-size: 14px;
}

optgroup option::before {
  content: "";
}
```

```html
DEMO 1 - Removing OPTGROUP tag

<form class="timePeriodMenu demo-1">
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <select name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2" multiple>
      <option value="1">last 30 days</option>
      <option value="6" selected="selected">past 6 months</option>
      <option value="12">past 12 months</option>
      <option value="300">list all</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<hr> DEMO 2 - Keeping Optgroup, but removing vertical-space with CSS hack.

<form class="timePeriodMenu demo-2">
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <select name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2" multiple>
      <optgroup label="German Cars">
        <option value="1">last 30 days</option>
        <option value="6" selected="selected">past 6 months</option>
        <option value="12">past 12 months</option>
        <option value="300">list all</option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

EDIT:

What's interesting is **this space is added differently depending on the browser**. This fix worked for me in Chrome and Opera but in **Firefox** I had to add:

```
padding-left: 0px;
```

To the **option** elements.

FURTHER EDIT:

- In **IE** that appears to just be the way an optgroup option is rendered and 
  I could not find a solution.
- In **Edge** the whole menu was collapsed on itself so I didn't even try 
  there.
- Not sure what's the case in **Safari** as I don't have that on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1. [Remove the optgroup element](https://jsfiddle.net/wccnuxgt/3/)
2. [Actually use the optgroup label attribute](https://jsfiddle.net/wccnuxgt/1/)

**Solution 1:**

```
<form class="timePeriodMenu">
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <select name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2" multiple>
            <option value="1">last 30 days</option>
            <option value="6" selected="selected">past 6 months</option>
            <option value="12">past 12 months</option>
            <option value="300">list all</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Solution 2:**

```
<form class="timePeriodMenu">
    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <select name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2" multiple>
            <optgroup label="here is your label">
                <option value="1">last 30 days</option>
                <option value="6" selected="selected">past 6 months</option>
                <option value="12">past 12 months</option>
                <option value="300">list all</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
<form class="timePeriodMenu">
  <div class="ui-field-contain">
    <select name="select-native-2" id="select-native-2" multiple>

      <option value="1">last 30 days</option>
      <option value="6" selected="selected">past 6 months</option>
      <option value="12">past 12 months</option>
      <option value="300">list all</option>

    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Alos check: [HTML optgroup Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_optgroup.asp)